# How to achieve a backward cycle hotkey in mpv?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mpv

MPV easily lets you cycle between values with one hotkey. For example using the `h` key to cycle between aspect ratios of `16:9`, `4:3`, `2.35:1`, `-1` and so on:

```
h cycle-values video-aspect-override "16:9" "4:3" "2.35:1" "-1"
```

It is also possible to do a similar thing with video rotation:

```
j cycle_values video-rotate 90 180 270 360 0
```

I am looking to achieve a way to cycle backwards, so I can pair the `J` key with another key. `F` will rotate counter clockwise, while `J` rotates clockwise

So with the above example in mind, if the current ration is at `270`, pressing `F` will set the rotation to `180`, while pressing `J` will set it to `360`

I would like to do this with **video-aspect**, **video-rotate** etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `!reverse` argument that you can use, e.g.:

```
f cycle_values "!reverse" video-rotate 90 180 270 360 0
```

See [documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#command-interface-cycle-values):

> The special argument `!reverse` can be used to cycle the value list in reverse. The only advantage is that you don't need to reverse the value list yourself when adding a second key binding for cycling backwards.

You can reverse it yourself using a tool like [this](https://phrasefix.com/tools/flip-words/).